# Как отобразить в ComboBox два поля обьекта?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть ComboBox в котором нужно выводить информацию из двух полей (`cust_name`  и `cust_Surname`). Получается выгрести только `cust_name`. Как вывести  `cust_name`  и `cust_Surname` в одной строке?

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Customer"
              Grid.Column="1" 
              Grid.Row="1"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              DisplayMemberPath="cust_name"  
              ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElementCustomers}"
              Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
              BorderBrush="{StaticResource brushWatermarkBorder}"/>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" ...>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding cust_name}"/>
                <Run Text=" / "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding cust_Surname}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, помогло. Подскажите, как при редактировании выводить информацию в Combobox?  _window.NameComboBox.Text=" "; - не работает

Comment: @Artyom: По идее, нужно установить `SelectedItem`. Лучше через `Binding`, конечно.

Comment: @ VladD :  Я имел ввиду если из кода c# устанавливать значение по умолчанию, как лучше сделать?

Comment: @Artyom: Вот так лучше и делать. Если у вас MVVM, в VM установите свойство `SelectedCustomer`, и прибиндьте к нему `SelectedItem`. Если не MVVM, напишите что-то наподобие `Combobox.SelectedItem = Customers.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @Artyom: Эээ, подождите, откуда вдруг внезапно взялся грид?

Comment: Из кода c#( при редактировании своей строки) присваиваю значения выбраного заказа, записываю значения  в textBox и  Combobox, как присвоить Comboboxу  строку? _window.NameComboBox.Text="Hello World" - не работает

Comment: @Artyom: Вы вовсе не должны работать с комбобоксом из кода, это ж не WinForms. Сделайте как в [этом комментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583184/583199?noredirect=1#comment778454_583199), и работайте с `SelectedCustomer`.